# Removing from ArrayList using Iterator. Won't give error but won't remove

Tags: java, button, javafx, arraylist, iterator

I am having trouble with my code. 
This button `delete`is meant to delete an object of type `Employee` from the ArrayList `emp`. The program receives input from the user in a `TextField` `delUsername` and that input will be the username of the Employee that has to be deleted. `getUsername` is a getter method of class `User` which `Employee` extends.

```
delete.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        for(Employee x : rw.readEmployee()){
            Iterator itr = rw.readEmployee().iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                Employee e = (Employee) itr.next();
                if(delUsername.getText().equals(x.getUsername())){
                    itr.remove();
                }
            }
            (new AdminView(admin)).show(st);
            st.show();
        }           
}});
```

The compiler will run the code and everything will work normally, without errors. However, the element will not be removed.
How can I make this work?

```
private File fUser;
private ArrayList<Employee> emp

public ArrayList<Employee> readEmployee() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fUser);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        emp = (ArrayList<Employee>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File not Found!!!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Class not Found!!!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("File not accessable!!!");
    }
    return emp;
}
```

Comment: Is the `remove()` method definitely being called?

Comment: You may remove the 'for each loop', and keep what's inside

Comment: Add a println where the remove is, and look if it passed ther

Comment: what does rw.readEmployee() actually do?

Comment: Why are there two loops?

Comment: also, you're saying in the question that "This button delete is meant to delete an object of type Employee from the ArrayList emp", but I see no `emp` in your code anywhere.

Comment: Those 2 loops should result in a `ConcurrentModificationException` unless `readEmployee` creates a new list every time invoked or none of the element matches. Furthermore on a match the list becomes completely empty, if there is a match and remains the same otherwise. The [`removeIf` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf%28java.util.function.Predicate%29) may be interesting for you, but if you create different lists or the input isn't correctly matched, this won't work either.

Comment: `Iterator itr = rw.readEmployee().iterator();  
       while(itr.hasNext()){
                Employee e = (Employee) itr.next();
                if(delUsername.getText().equals(x.getUsername())){
                    itr.remove();
                }
            (new AdminView(admin)).show(st);
            st.show();
        }`

Comment: @eis 
    public ArrayList<Employee> readEmployee(){
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fUser);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            emp = (ArrayList<Employee>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   System.err.println("File not Found!!!");
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   System.err.println("Class not Found!!!");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.err.println("File not accessable!!!");
  }
  return emp;
 }

Comment: @eis `UserRW` class which has private variables File fUser and ArrayList<Employee> emp

Comment: @SteveSmith How can I know?

Comment: How do you display the contents of the list? It's not passed to any method and you open multiple `AdminView`s, and I don't know if any of those gains access to one of the lists created. However every time you call `readEmployee` you read the content of the file to a new list which  a) requires `n+1` file accesses where `n` is the number of `Employee`s in the file and b) drops the modified lists (except for possibly the last one). Since the file contents are not changed, `readEmployee` calls always result a list with the same contents.